# GitPython Read a branch without it existing locally or cloning

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm trying to read a branch from a Git repository without having a local copy or cloning the repo.

The GitPython API seems to assume a repo either exists locally or you with to clone it to read it.

All i'd like to do is access all the commits from a branch, for a repo, without it existing locally.

I'm after something like this:

```py
    branch = git.Repo(https://github.com/MyOrg/MyRepo, 'master')

    for commit in branch.commits:
        print(commit)
```

I'm looking at the API and I just don't see anything like this.

Is this possible?

Comment: "*The GitPython API seems to assume a repo either exists locally or you with to clone it to read it.*" With `GitPython` having a repo locally is the only way. The library doesn't work with remote repos simply because `git` doesn't work with remote repos; `git` can only clone, fetch, pull, push and ls-remote (but `GitPython` doesn't properly do ls-remote AFAIK). For GitHub you try GH-specific libraries that use [GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-api): https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/libraries#python

Comment: @phd Thanks. Is there one you've used/you could recommend?

Comment: I think PyGithub and github3.py are the most popular.